# Cold air until I unplug and replug in the thermostat

Tags: thermostat, furnace

Why is My Honeywell thermostat reading the temperature as lower than the set temperature and blowing cold air until I unplug it and replug it in. Then it blows warm air? This has happened a few times. Mostly in the evening. What should I do?

Comment: Model # of thermostat? If you leave the thermostat plugged in but turn it from Heat to Off, wait 5 seconds, turn back to Heat, does that work?

Comment: What make and model is your furnace/air-handler?

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is in the furnace, not the thermostat. It sounds like it has gone into lockout mode. One could check the circuit boards at the furnace to see whether there is any flashing LED or other indicator that could reveal what the controls are doing.

Comment: Does the stat indicate that it's heating, before you cycle it?